# How can I launch the cmd or execute a cmd command in the client side, using like JavaScript, jQuery or typescript and so on ? on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, cmd, command, client-side

I want to execute a cmd command but in the client side not in the server side, can i do that with JavaScript for example on chrome ?

Comment: Ccan you specify "_a cmd command_"? If you mean you want to execute something on the command line on the client's OS, that's not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by execute a command? You can of course write instructions in JavaScript that your browser will execute.

Comment: @Mushroomator i think cmd command is a command for the windows cmd terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reason this is not allowed and it is safety. Imagine those horrible things someone can do if they had access to your terminal.
If you mean the server instead, look for a program like nodejs for server side js code.